# How to connect user and groups when user registration in django

Tags: python, django

I m trying to create a user management app with django. When creating a new user, it includes all data to corresponding fields, except the groups field.
I use django auth models and generic base view

So far this is my code

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):

  password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
  confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'password', 'confirm_password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'groups']
```

views.py

```
class RegisterFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
   login_url = '/user/login'

   user_class = UserRegisterForm
   profile_class = ProfileForm
   template_name = 'user/registration_form.html'

   # Display blank form
   def get(self, request):
      form = self.user_class(None)
      form_1 = self.profile_class(None)
      context = {
         'form': form,
         'form_1': form_1
      }
      return render(request, self.template_name, context)

  # Process form data
  def post(self, request):
    form = self.user_class(request.POST)
    form_1 = self.profile_class(request.POST, request.FILES)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'form_1': form_1
    }

    if form.is_valid() and form_1.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        # Clean data
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        confirm_password = form.cleaned_data["confirm_password"]

        if password != confirm_password:
            raise form.ValidationError(
                "password and confirm_password does not match"
            )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        profile = form_1.save(commit=False)
        form_1.cleaned_data['image']
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()

        # Returns user
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                return redirect('user:accounts')

    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

template

```
   <table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>

                                        <th>Username</th>
                                        <th>First Name</th>
                                        <th>Last Name</th>
                                        <th>Group</th>
                                            <th>Edit</th>
                                            <th>Delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                {% for user in all_user %}
                                    <tr>
                                            <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                                            <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{user.groups}}</td>
                                            <td><a href="{% url 'user:user-update' user.id %}"
                                                   class="btn btn-link"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <form action="{% url 'user:user-delete' user.id %}"
                                                      method="post">
                                                        {% csrf_token%}
                                                    <button name="delete" value="{{user.id}}"
                                                        class="btn btn-link"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                                                </form>
                                            </td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

The output must be "A_Group", but it outputs "auth.Group.None"

Comment: what do you mean by "output"?

Comment: @PawełKordowski, Currently, i print user details from user table

Comment: Can you include template?

Comment: What's your input data for group field?